# Facing error while installing Stellargraph on Windows PC

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

Here is the error message:

> ERROR: thinc 6.12.1 has requirement wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0, but you'll
>   have wrapt 1.11.2 which is incompatible.
>
> Installing collected packages: wrapt, tensorflow, stellargraph.  Found
>   existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
>
> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project
>   and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Please help me with this installation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question so that it can be understood well. I also indented the text. Good Luck!

Comment: Try installing from a virtual environment.

Comment: Hi @JayaKrishnan, I work on stellargraph, and would love to know more about what you did here. Did you just run `pip install stellargraph`? And, did you have a previously installed version of `stellargraph` or `tensorflow` or `wrapt`? (If you haven't fixed the problem yet, you can run `pip list` to list all of your installed packages, and find those ones within it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pip install --ignore-installed -U wrapt
```

or

```
conda update wrapt
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Cannot+uninstall+%27wrapt%27.+It+is+a+distutils+installed+project+and+thus+we+cannot+accurately+determine+which+files+belong+to+it+which+would+lead+to+only+a+partial+uninstall

and

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Cannot+uninstall+It+is+a+distutils+installed+project+and+thus+we+cannot+accurately+determine+which+files+belong+to+it+which+would+lead+to+only+a+partial+uninstall.